# MyBatis+Redis caching. Is it possible?

Tags: java, spring, caching, redis, mybatis

I have a small project just to check how everything works. I've implemented the usage of MyBatis and the project just works, I was able to retrieve some data from a database. But right now I need the result to be cached for the 2nd time. I've already tested redis to be an embedded cache manager in spring(cache abstraction: http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-redis/docs/current/reference/html/redis.html and liker here: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.0.M1/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html). I've implemented everything and cached one method. BUT!!!
I can't really understand was it cached or not. The first time when I marked up the method, redis said, that there are changes to the db and saved it.. but then I changed the key, and nothing changed... How do I understand, that the method was cached or not?? I will put some code here for you to understand what I'm doing.

Spring Context:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:cache="http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache"
       xmlns:c="http://www.springframework.org/schema/c"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:redis="http://www.springframework.org/schema/redis"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" 
       xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc" 
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" 
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.1.xsd 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/redis http://www.springframework.org/schema/redis/spring-redis.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache.xsd   
        ">

    <jdbc:embedded-database id="dataSource" type="H2"> 
        <jdbc:script location="file:src/main/java/schema.sql" /> 
        <jdbc:script location="file:src/main/java/test-data.sql" />
    </jdbc:embedded-database>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" /> 
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven />

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.mycompany.mybatisproject.serviceimpl" />

    <!-- Define the SqlSessionFactory --> 
    <bean id="sqlSessionFactory" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean"> 
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="mapperLocations" value="file:src/main/java/com/mycompany/mybatisproject/persistence/ContactMapper.xml" />
        <property name="typeAliasesPackage" value="com.mycompany.mybatisproject.data" /> 
    </bean>

    <!-- classpath*:com/mycompany/mybatisproject/persistence/*.xml -->

    <!-- Scan for mappers and let them be autowired -->
    <bean class="org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperScannerConfigurer">
        <property name="basePackage" value="com.mycompany.mybatisproject.persistence" />
        <property name="sqlSessionFactory" ref="sqlSessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="jedisConnectionFactory" class="org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory"
    p:host-name="localhost" p:port="6379" />

    <bean id="redisTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jedisConnectionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <cache:annotation-driven />

    <bean id="cacheManager" class="org.springframework.data.redis.cache.RedisCacheManager" 
        c:template-ref="redisTemplate" />

</beans>
```

Implementation of service:

```
@Service("contactService")
@Repository
@Transactional
public class ContactServiceImpl implements ContactService {

    private Log log = LogFactory.getLog(ContactServiceImpl.class);

    @Autowired
    private ContactMapper contactMapper;

    @Cacheable("pacan")
    @Transactional(readOnly=true)
    public List<Contact> findAll() {
        List<Contact> contacts = contactMapper.findAll();
        return contacts;
    }
}
```

ContactMapper.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE mapper PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Mapper 3.0//EN" 
"http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-mapper.dtd">
<mapper namespace="com.mycompany.mybatisproject.persistence.ContactMapper">

    <resultMap id="contactResultMap" type="Contact">
        <id property="id" column="ID" />
        <result property="firstName" column="FIRST_NAME" />
        <result property="lastName" column="LAST_NAME" /> 
        <result property="birthDate" column="BIRTH_DATE" />
    </resultMap>

    <select id="findAll" resultMap="contactResultMap">
        SELECT ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, BIRTH_DATE 
        FROM CONTACT
    </select>
```

And finally the main class:

```
public class App {

    private static void ListContacts(List<Contact> contacts) {
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Listing contacts without details: ");
        for (Contact contact : contacts) {
            System.out.println(contact);
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        GenericXmlApplicationContext ctx = new GenericXmlApplicationContext();
        ctx.load("file:src/main/java/app-context.xml");
        ctx.refresh();

        ContactService contactService = ctx.getBean("contactService", ContactService.class);

        List<Contact> contacts;
        contacts = contactService.findAll(); 
        ListContacts(contacts);
    }    
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're caching invocation of ContactServiceImpl.findAll method. For test purpose you can add System.out.println("Method invoked") in findAll method. If the cache works the body of findAll method should be invoked only once, next invocations should read value (result) from cache so you shouldn't see "Method invoked" on console.

Don't use Spring 3.1.0.M1 documentation it is different from 3.1.0.RELEASE: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.0.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer. So, as I understood from the link, I have to declare in the xml the method, that should be cached?

Comment: No, you don't. It is enough to mark a method with @Cacheable, add to xml: <cache:annotation-driven /> and define cacheManager bean. At the beginning you may try org.springframework.cache.support.SimpleCacheManager and if it works switch to redis.